# Laravel 5.2.43 vs 5.2.45 (Eloquent Sum returns null instead of 0)?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

Just wanted to understand the difference between the 2 mentioned versions, Laravel v.5.2.43 and v.5.2.45.

I have observed the following difference:

```
// 5.2.43
// Returns 0 in case if there nothing with name Coffee
Product::where('name','Coffee')->sum('weight');

// 5.2.45
// Returns NULL in case if there nothing with name Coffee
Product::where('name','Coffee')->sum('weight');
```

I have a reporting tool, and the entire operations are collapsing when the value returned in NULL instead of a 0 in previous version.

My query here is that, is it a feature or a bug? If feature, is there a better alternative for changing the behavior? Or I have to change my code to accept this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing the The sum methods of \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
( file located at: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php )

**Laravel 5.2.43**

```
 /**
 * Retrieve the sum of the values of a given column.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @return float|int
 */
    public function sum($column)
    {
        $result = $this->aggregate(__FUNCTION__, [$column]);

        return $result ?: 0;
    }
```

**Laravel 5.2.45:**

```
/**
 * Retrieve the sum of the values of a given column.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @return mixed
 */
public function sum($column)
{
    return $this->aggregate(__FUNCTION__, [$column]);
}
```

So in 5.43 if $result was NULL instead 0 was returned.

I am not entirely sure if that is intended behaviour by the devs because 
for example the count() function has a cast to (int) in 5.2.45

```
return (int) $this->aggregate(__FUNCTION__, $columns);
```

Also have a look at the [commit history](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commits/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php) of that file: 
They fixed the aggregate funcions by using numericAggreate(), but this was later reverted again.

As it is a breaking change for some apps, I would say this unwanted behaviour, but I'm not completely sure.

You are free to create a new [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen) in the laravel github repository.

Until then, you have only 3 Choices:

1. Go back to Laravel 5.43  ( by updating composer.json )  OR
2. Adjust your code to deal with null values.
3. Temporarily change the vendor source code ( but I would not recommend this )

Comment: Yea, seems fair, I guessed so. I believe its a bug as by default you expect an integer. I will just raise an issue for now and fallback to 5.2.43 for now..! Thanks a lot :)